# What's a regex to strip out both HTML tags and their contents from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to capture everything between two HTML tags, both the contents and the tags. I suppose it doesn't have to be that robust, but ideally it could handle this kind of edge case:

```
foo <div>>bar</div>> baz
```

Return should be:

```
foo > baz
```

**What I've tried:**

There are a plenty of [RegExs for stripping out HTML tags](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/) but I haven't found anything that also strips out the contents. So far I have this:

```
\<(.*)\>
```

But that is greedy and returns

```
foo  bar
```

Comment: Don't use RegEx, parse the HTML.  Also, why do you need to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "parse the HTML"?

Comment: @ggundersen You can use the DOM, which is the parsed HTML. Then you can access the `childNodes` properties of a DOM element individually. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616659/227299)

Comment: *JavaScript* and using RegEx for HTML elements? *Oh my*.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var subject = "foo <div>>bar</div>> baz";
var result = subject.replace(/^(.*?)(?:<.*>)(.*?)$/, "$1>$2");
console.log(result);
//foo > baz
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/67wRY/)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You could parse the DOM instead of using RegExp:

```
var text = [];
var TEXT_NODE = 3;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
   document.getElementById('test').childNodes,
   function (n) {
      if (n.nodeType === TEXT_NODE)
         text.push(n.textContent)
   }
);
console.log(text.join(''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S5CT3/

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for Regex, [but you can do it more robustly by interacting with the DOM](http://jsfiddle.net/X4DjU/3/)

```
<div id="test">foo <div>>bar</div>> baz</div>
alert(
    document.getElementById('test').firstChild.nodeValue +
    document.getElementById('test').lastChild.nodeValue
); 
// foo > baz
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to borrow @JuanMendes' answer here, but generalise it - after all, you might have more than just two nodes like that ;)

```
function strip(source) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = source;
    var nodes = div.childNodes;
    var retarr = [];
    for( var i = nodes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if( nodes[i].nodeType == 3) retarr.unshift(nodes[i].nodeValue);
    }
    return retarr.join("");
}

var html = "foo <div>>bar</div>> baz";
alert(strip(html)); // foo > baz
```

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CnyP2/)